# FMX TListView.Sort dont work in delphi 10.3.3

Tags: delphi

I am trying to sort a TListView in alphabetical order but the method I am using does not seem to work.

here is the call code:

```
procedure TfMain.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
miSort.IsChecked := not miSort.IsChecked; // miSort is a TMenuItem in a TPopupMenu
if miSort.IsChecked then
   begin
   lvLinks.BeginUpdate;
   lvLinks.Sort(AlphaSort);
   lvLinks.EndUpdate;
   end;
end;
```

The Sort method require a TFmxObjectSortCompare

```
TFmxObjectSortCompare = reference to function (Left, Right: TFMXObject): Integer;
```

, there is mine:

```
function AlphaSort(Left, Right: TFMXObject): Integer;
begin
result := CompareText(TListViewItem(Left).Text, TListViewItem(Right).Text) // require System.SysUtils
end;
```

It dont work both with or without BeginUpdate...EndUpdate.

Comment: Not related to the issue, but still: you need to protect `BeginUpdate..EndUpdate` with a `try..finally` block. Otherwise, if an exception is raised in `Sort`, you'll get stuck in the `BeginUpdate` state, which is very bad. Always do it like this: `lvLinks.BeginUpdate; try {do stuff} finally lvLinks.EndUpdate; end` (but with proper whitespace and indenting, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In FMX `TListView` is inherited from `TAdapterListView`, which exposes an `Adapter` property of type `IListViewAdapter`. This interface provides a `Sort` method for the list items.

According to your example this approach should probably be valid:

```
  lvLinks.Adapter.Sort(TDelegatedComparer<TListItem>.Create(
    function(const Left, Right: TListItem): Integer
    begin
      Result := CompareText(TListViewItem(Left).Text, TListViewItem(Right).Text);
    end));
```